# Displaying route details from direction render marker in Google map v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

I tried to display road network info in the respective infoWindow generated by Direction

Render marker.E.g Marker A when click the infoWindow contain all details from A to B.

Besides, an array of waypoints are shown between the source and destination.  The

informations are not shown on InfoWindow popup. Here is part of the code. Any hint might

help thanks.

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

            var roadInfo = document.getElementById("directionsPanel");

            roadInfo.innerHTML="<b>"+response.routes[0].roadInfo+"</b>";

                directionDisplay.setDirections(response);

            var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
                google.maps.event.addListener(request, 'click', function() {
                // Open an info window when the marker is clicked on,

                // containing the text of the step.

                displayStep.setContent(request,myRoute.steps[i].instructions);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no click-event for request, the infowWindow you see when you click on a marker is forced by the directionRenderer and you don't have any control over the markers and infoWindows, the only thing you can do is to suppress them
2. a route doesn't have a roadInfo

What you can do: suppress the markers and infoWindow's and create your own.